# In mediawiki anchor link with img tag in html content not getting perfect

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am  new to mediawiki and am using html content to view the image , I need to get image with anchor tag . I created the code but it will not shown the image, Its just display the code itself.

```
$fullPageHtml = Html::openElement('img',array('src' => '/mediawiki/images/god.png',
                                         'alt' => 'alt'));
$fullPageHtml .= Html::closeElement('img');
```

If i make a space after the "alt" tag , when i use firebug it will show the image but otherwise it won't. Any solutions

Comment: Where did you put that code? Does it appear as is in the browser?

Comment: Its looks as a code, In browser it displays as  <a href="oh"><img src="/mediawiki/images/god.png" alt="" /></a>

Comment: I written the output in addHtml function now the image is getting with anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Harsha's answer: wrap the HTML in the `addHtml()` function instead of `Html::openElement()`.